# iOS objective c replacing uitabbar with a button but button has no interaction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitabbar

I believe this scenario would be very typical one but I cannot get it work. Here is my views relationship : an extended UITabBarController (A) -> UINavigationController (B) -> extended UIViewController as root view controller (C) -> target view controller (D) with a UIButton (E).

Initially, the root view controller, which is a collection view is showing, then push to D, during D's initialization, in viewWillAppear and viewWillLayoutSubviews , I put code to hide the tabbar A and keep the navigation bar of B showing, and set D's view to a new frame height to make sure it can cover the full screen, then layout the UIButton E frame to exactly the tabbar A's frame.

The result is that the button E is displaying properly, at the previous tabbar's position, but it does not response to any gesture or touchupinside events.

Below is the code of D :

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height)];
    [_button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, screenRect.size.height - buttonHeight - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height, screenRect.size.width, buttonHeight)];
    [self.view addSubview:_button];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_button];
}
```

I tried using

```
[self.view insertSubview:_button atIndex:0]
```

too, and checked the view hierarchy in debugger, all *LOOKS* good except no interaction events fired.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: i think your hierarchy look like a messaging app ( tabbar controller -> history -- > your collection View ( a view controller ) & you want to hide tabbar when you pushed ?

Comment: Yes, i want tabbar hide when i am pushing a specific view into navigation controller. This is working, but the button on the view is not clickable at the tabor's location. If I do not hide the tabbar, and do not set the button to that position, it is working very well, but that is not what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
youNextViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:youNextViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: if i got you issue as true , this code work for you  :)

Comment: In general situations, I believe your answer would hide the tabbar properly, but i just found i did not describe my question clearly enough. My views hierarchy is more complex, so I had to examine the view hierarchy via debugger carefully to find out which super view frame is smaller than expected, that would be the root cause of the button could not be clicked, because the button was outside of that frame and could not receive interaction events. Thanks!